# Inconsistent results when “using timestamp” on YugabyteDB YCQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I'm trying to upsert, delete and upsert the same record using `using timestamp` syntax. The first upsert and delete are successful. After I delete the record, if I upsert the same record again, the update status is true, but the select statement is not showing the row.

```
ycqlsh:test> CREATE TABLE todo (     id   int,     seq  int,     task text,     status boolean,     primary key (id, seq) );
ycqlsh:test> insert into todo(id, seq, task, status) values(1, 1, 'sample', false);
ycqlsh:test> insert into todo(id, seq, task, status) values(1, 2, 'sample2', false);
ycqlsh:test> select * from todo;

 id | seq | task    | status
----+-----+---------+--------
  1 |   1 |  sample |  False
  1 |   2 | sample2 |  False

(2 rows)
ycqlsh:test> UPDATE todo using timestamp 1000 SET status = false, task='sample3' WHERE id=1 and seq=3 returns status as row;

 [applied] | [message] | id   | seq  | task | status
-----------+-----------+------+------+------+--------
      True |      null | null | null | null |   null

ycqlsh:test> select * from todo;

 id | seq | task    | status
----+-----+---------+--------
  1 |   1 |  sample |  False
  1 |   2 | sample2 |  False
  1 |   3 | sample3 |  False

(3 rows)
ycqlsh:test> delete from todo WHERE id=1 and seq=3;
ycqlsh:test> select * from todo;

 id | seq | task    | status
----+-----+---------+--------
  1 |   1 |  sample |  False
  1 |   2 | sample2 |  False

(2 rows)
ycqlsh:test> UPDATE todo using timestamp 2000 SET status = false, task='sample3' WHERE id=1 and seq=3 returns status as row;

 [applied] | [message] | id   | seq  | task | status
-----------+-----------+------+------+------+--------
      True |      null | null | null | null |   null

ycqlsh:test> select * from todo;

 id | seq | task    | status
----+-----+---------+--------
  1 |   1 |  sample |  False
  1 |   2 | sample2 |  False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use `DELETE` without `USING`. To reintroduce the row back into the table, you have to use `UPDATE` without `USING TIMESTAMP`.

The correct usage should have been:

```
delete from todo USING TIMESTAMP 1000 id=1 and seq=3;
```

If you want `DELETE` without the use of `USING timestamp`... then you should use timestamp values that are actually close to physical time in microseconds since epoch rather than numbers like `1000` or `2000`.